# In the context of likelihood, why is the log-density considered to be more "natural" than the density?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, intuition

Working through some notes and it says that one of the reasons for using the log-likelihood rather than the likelihood is that the "log-likelihood is a the more "natural" and relevant quantity" in comparison to the likelihood.

I know why the log-likelihood is the more relevant quantity(e.g Fisher information) but why is it considered to be more "natural" than the likeihood?

Comment: It's not really more natural. It does turns out that likelihood is often easier to handle on a logarithmic scale. Algebraically that means taking terms out of exponentials and converting multiplications to additions.  Then for the same reason using logarithms is a defence against difficulties in handling really big or really small numbers for the likelihood, as are all too likely in very many problems. But in one sense using logarithms is like any use of logarithms: consider pH, decibels, logarithm of income, etc., which people in their fields find convenient and with repetition familiar.

Comment: @Nick The log likelihood actually *is* more natural because it is directly related to key statistics like the information matrix and KL divergence.

Comment: The likelihood comes first before you can even take its logarithm.  Cue endless quasi-theological discussion about what is "natural".

Comment: @Nick Because the logarithm is mathematically equivalent to the original value, it's meaningless to say one "comes first." What matters is what expressions have useful or insightful interpretations. In the maximum likelihood theory, there is no question the log likelihood enjoys many such interpretations, whereas the likelihood itself is just asymptotically zero--scarcely of any interest. In general, the log likelihood is more directly related to the affine connection on spaces of distributions. These are real mathematical matters, not questions of counting dancing angels.

Comment: As a mathematician, and I naturally agree, you can point out that one could define log-likelihood first and then call its exponentiation likelihood (or use other names as appeal). Historically and pedagogically, however, likelihood comes first, I think. If you can find anyone explaining log-likelihood (again, any other name will do) before they explain likelihood, that would be interesting. I think it is topsy-turvy to regard the information matrix and KL divergence as in some sense more fundamental than the likelihood expression that defines a model, if that is what you are implying.

Comment: @Nick I'm not trying to imply that. I am trying to convey the realization I had long ago when I first understood that the log likelihood was far more useful than as a mere tool for simplifying derivations or performing computations: from it emerge fundamentally useful and illuminating results such as the asymptotic chi-squared distribution of twice the difference of log likelihoods. Although that could be considered the equivalent of a "log-chi-squared" distribution of the likelihood ratio, the origin of this distribution in the Central Limit Theorem--applied to the *logs*-- provides insight.

Comment: I am just trying to hold up one side of a miniature debate, but once you underline _useful_ it seems that the argument is morphing away from _natural_, and useful is what my first comment emphasises too. You have a much deeper understanding of the theory than I do, but a muddy-handed practitioner's view is of some relevance, I suggest.

Comment: The title perhaps should be fixed to be closer to the question.

Comment: The question is indeed a little ill-posed. Naturalness doesn't seem to be a relevant metric, or at least something that is well defined. And making statements from notes without citation or context seems at least vague, if one is being benevolent. I'd suggest that a clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to think about how likelihood ratios behave. It's a ratio, so it's x:y, where x and y are both non-negative numbers. So the ratio can range from 0 to infinite, with a midpoint at 1. That's pretty inconvenient to work with. If you take log(x:y), you end up with a scale running from negative infinity to positive infinity, with a midpoint at 0.

Having a midpoint in the middle of the scale is nice, but that's not all that happened. Notice that each "unit" in a likelihood ratio is of different value. That is, the difference between 0 to 1 is MUCH larger than the difference from 1 to 2. That is, if you can improve your odds from "impossible" to even, that's enormous. Improving from even to a 2:1 ratio is still pretty good, but not as big a deal. Similarly, improving your odds from 1:1 to 2:1 is still very good, but not nearly so meaningful.

If you use log(x:y), the units end up being of equal value. The different between 0 and 1 is the same as from 1 to 2 is the same as from 2 to 3, and so on.